# How to connect Unity with Arduino using Bluetooth module?

Tags: unity, google-cardboard, bluetooth

I will be getting data in real-time from an Arduino. I want to display that data (such as rpm of a bike) in my Unity game and use it to control the subjects in the game.

I have Bluetooth module HC-05 which I want to use to send the data from the Arduino to Unity.  I found a plugin for this on Unity store but it costs $20.

Could you guide me on how to include Bluetooth access in Unity as well as Arduino?

Comment: Did you found any way? I am working on a same project.